# When I use \cite{} in Beamer, the link points to the slide number rather then the bibliography ?

Tags: beamer, bibtex

When I use \cite{} from BibTex in Beamer, the link points to the slide number rather then the bibliography ?  is this normal ? How to fix it ?

Comment: General comment: When using beamer, it is better not to provide a bibliography, since it is supposed to be a presentation... thus, references are better include as `\footnote`s. However, an answer to your question would be useful!

Comment: Please add a *complete*, *minimal* document allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've used BibTeX with beamer, no troubles. But mostly with `\cite{*}` or `\nocite{....}`.